# Getting angles in my 2d circles when using texture in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am building my first 2D mobile game using unity, everything works as expected when I create a circle with a new default Material, but when I use a Material that has a Shader and a texture the circle shows angles.

I am using unity 2020.2.1f1 with Universal Render Pipeline running on Linux.

I have attached an image of the problem, the left circle uses a Material with Shader and texture and the right one uses a Material without texture.

**I would like the left circle to be also a proper circle as the one in the right side.**

[Circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1ERC.png)

[Shader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cHyQ.png)

There is also an error that says `Material does not have _MainTex texture property. It is required for SprintRenderer` But when I add that as reference of the property, the texture is not shown at all. I don't know if that could be related.

Answer (score 0):

When I install unity 2019.4.19f1 the circle is rendered as I expected. So that is how I fixed it.

The message:
`Material does not have _MainTex texture property. It is required for SprintRenderer`
wasn't related with the problem.